# how to move to next cell/row in table view with textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfielddelegate

i am stuck at this .please help me in sorting out this issue.
this is my image now i have 5 different rows in the table.
if u click on first textfield after editing the first field then i want  done button click to goto the second field and open textview and textfield simulatneously(as shown in the image).
The **Category** Filed is having picker view,The **Name** field (shown in image),**Location** is having same as image,**price** is having a action sheet.

Now i have added code for action sheet of **Price Field** .Can somebody help me achieve the required.Thanks for help... :)

[image]

i am doing something like this but it is not yet worked for me.
the code is:

```
- (void) textFieldDoneTouched
{

    [self.site setValue:textField.text forIndex:selectedRow];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect f = textFieldContainerView.frame;
                         f.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
                         textFieldContainerView.frame = f;
                     }];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:selectedRow inSection:0];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];

    [self validateSiteData];
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

        [self textFieldDoneTouched];
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITextViewDelegate

- (void) textViewDoneTouched
{




    [self.site setValue:textView.text forIndex:selectedRow];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect f = textViewContainerView.frame;
                         f.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
                         textViewContainerView.frame = f;
                     }];

    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:selectedRow inSection:0];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self validateSiteData];
}


#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate

- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet1 clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if(buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.site.price = @"Free";
       // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:4 inSection:0];

       // [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:100];
        //[textField resignFirstResponder];
       // [textView becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.site.price = @"Paid ($)";
       // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:4 inSection:0];

      //  [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:100];
       // [textField resignFirstResponder];
         //[textView becomeFirstResponder];
        }


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:selectedRow inSection:0];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    [self validateSiteData];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you'd like the iPhone's return key to go to the next field, like pressing Tab on a computer keyboard?

One minor note: I'd recommend using the default grey "return" key, not the blue "Done" key in your screenshot. "Done" is for when the user is *done* filling out the form and the keyboard should disappear; "return" is for going to the next field or row of text, as in Apple's Contacts app.

[image: Apple Contacts]

Like Apple's Contacts app, I'd also recommend that your UITextFields be in the same UITableViewCells as their labels (Category, Name...).  I find the text field directly above the keyboard in your screenshot a little confusing. If you do that, then the following implementation of `textFieldShouldReturn` will make the next cell's text field into the first responder.

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
    // Determine the row number of the active UITextField in which "return" was just pressed.
    id cellContainingFirstResponder = textField.superview.superview ;
    NSInteger rowOfCellContainingFirstResponder = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cellContainingFirstResponder].row ;
    // Get a reference to the next cell.
    NSIndexPath* indexPathOfNextCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowOfCellContainingFirstResponder+1 inSection:0] ;
    TableViewCell* nextCell = (TableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfNextCell] ;
    if ( nextCell )
        [nextCell.theTextField becomeFirstResponder] ;
    else
        [textField resignFirstResponder] ;
    return YES ;
}
```

Let me know if you'd like me to post the whole project.

[image: UITextFields inside UITableViewCells]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply.it would be much helpful if you provide the full code.Thnks...

Comment: Hi @John sauer .i tried with your code by changing : TableViewCell* nextCell as - UITableViewCell* nextCell but it didnot work with (gave error)=  [nextCell.theTextField becomeFirstResponder] ;      and so i  tried to change it as=  [textField becomeFirstResponder] ; but still its not working right for me... Please help out here.

Comment: [Here's the whole project](http://JohnSauerDeveloper.com/s/14582924-Return-key-go-to-next-field.zip). If you're familiar enough with Xcode and Cocoa, you should be able to figure out how it works and implement something similar in your own project.

Comment: thxs john i will try to work around the project and get what i need .cheers

Comment: Whole's project link expired.

Comment: David, [here is the project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o47y1kjsm8tsxxu/AADJUuIheZYUGTBCSPF5G_7-a?dl=0) on Dropbox; you'll find a download button in the corner. The Xcode project is 4-1/2 years old at this point, so I don't know how helpful it is anymore.